# How to get list of partitions of spring batch job running in master and slave tomcat

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I have worked on an Spring Batch Admin example by taking [Spring Batch Talk](https://github.com/mminella/Spring-Batch-Talk-2.0)  as reference. The example ran perfectly how I wanted. Using rabbit server, I have established communication between master and slave. But how can I know which partition is running in master and which is running in slave. Is there any chance to view it from Spring Batch Admin UI.

Comment: Without you doing some custom code, there really isn't a way to know who is running where.

Comment: Consider for sake of argument, Is there is any way to make odd partitions to work in slave and even in master? Is so, can I have any reference link or something to go over them @MichaelMinella

Answer (score 0):

While doing partitioning in `ColumnRangePartitioner`, I have added one more value partitionId to ExecutionContext.

```
value.putLong("minValue", start);
value.putLong("maxValue", end);
value.putLong("partitionId", number);
```

I have added a new column called partitionInfo to TARGET which stores the details like which port has been scanned in which partition. While reading ports, I have added explicitly values.

```
<bean id="targetItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader" scope="step">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="queryProvider">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean">
                <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
                <property name="selectClause" value="ID, IP, PORT, CONNECTED, BANNER, :partitionId as PARTITIONINFO" />
                <property name="fromClause" value="FROM TARGET" />
                <property name="whereClause" value="ID >= :minId AND ID &lt;= :maxId AND CONNECTED IS NULL"/>
                <property name="sortKey" value="ID" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="pageSize" value="10" />
        <property name="parameterValues">
            <map>
                <entry key="minId" value="#{stepExecutionContext[minValue]}"/>
                <entry key="maxId" value="#{stepExecutionContext[maxValue]}"/>
                <entry key="partitionId" value="#{stepExecutionContext[partitionId]}" />
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="rowMapper">
            <bean class="com.michaelminella.springbatch.domain.TargetRowMapper"/>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Later I ran update query at the end and saved the details in table.

```
<bean id="targetWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
        <property name="assertUpdates" value="true" />
        <property name="itemSqlParameterSourceProvider">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider" />
        </property>
        <property name="sql" value="UPDATE TARGET SET CONNECTED = :connected, BANNER = :banner, PARTITIONINFO = :partitionId WHERE ID = :id" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

I have added new variable to Target bean which stores partitionId information.

```
private int partitionId;

public int getPartitionId() {
    return partitionId;
}

public void setPartitionId(int partitionId) {
    this.partitionId = partitionId;
}
```

DB Changes in `business-schema-mysql.sql`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TARGET;

CREATE TABLE TARGET  (
    ID BIGINT  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
    IP VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    PORT INT NOT NULL,
    CONNECTED BOOLEAN NULL,
    BANNER VARCHAR(255),
    PARTITIONINFO INT
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```